# How to write this code in a class component using react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This code writes in function component using react hooks and I can use the class component to write this code but I will not understand how is this possible because react hooks are used only in function components.

Can anyone help me how is it possible

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

function Accordion(props) {
    const [setActive, setActiveState] = useState("");
    const [setHeight, setHeightState] = useState("0px");

    const content = useRef(null);

    function toggleAccordion() {
        setActiveState(setActive === "" ? "active" : "non-active");
        console.log(content);
        setHeightState(setActive === "active" ? "0px" : `${content.current.scrollHeight}px`);
      }

 return (
   <div className="accordion__section">
     <button className={`accordion ${setActive}`} onClick={toggleAccordion}>
       <div className="accordion__title"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.title }}
       />
     </button>
     <div ref={content} style={{ maxHeight: `${setHeight}` }}  className="accordion__content">
       <div
         className="accordion__text"
         dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.content }}
       />
     </div>
   </div>
 );
}

export default Accordion;
```

Comment: Instead of `useState` hook, use `setState` method to set the state. And of course, use the constructor to initialize the state.

Comment: This is not really related to the solution itself but it's worth to name your variables as `const [active, setActive] = useState('')` instead of `[setActive, setActiveState]`. It's easier to differentiate between the state value and the setter function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Accordion extends React.Component {
  state = {
    active: '',
    height: '0px',
  }

  content = React.createRef(null);

  toggleAccordion = () => {
    this.setState({
      active: this.state.active === "" ? "active" : "non-active",
      height: this.state.active === "active" ? "0px" : `${this.content.current.scrollHeight}px`
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="accordion__section">
        <button className={`accordion ${this.state.active}`} onClick={this.toggleAccordion}>
          <div className="accordion__title"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.title }}
          />
        </button>
        <div ref={content} style={{ maxHeight: this.state.height }}  className="accordion__content">
          <div
            className="accordion__text"
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.content }}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me! I have run this code they have no error but when I click the button they didn't expend there height to show hidden content

Comment: Can you create a sandbox?

Comment: I'll create a sandbox and write all coding. see that https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-mountain-jf13r?file=/src/component/accordion.js

Comment: You have a typo in your code. I fixed it. Look at this link -> https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-bash-foln8?file=/src/component/accordion.js

Comment: Ok Thanks, you solve my biggest problem I spend two days on this.